# Webpack bundle is not getting executed when splitChunks.chunks is set to 'all'

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I was updating my Webpack configuration for the Webpack 4. I'm setting `optimiztion` object as such(the full config file can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/iiison/372a7a96d75bbe3b475faacb29d93056)):

```
optimization : {
    minimize : isProduction,
    minimizer : [
      terserPlugin,
      optimizeCSSAssetsPlugin
    ],
    splitChunks : {
      // chunks : 'async',
      chunks : 'all',
      name   : false,
    },
    runtimeChunk : true,
  }
```

The problem is that my js code doesn't work if the value of `splitChunks.chunks` is set to `all` but everything works as expected when I change the value from `all` to `async`.

I couldn't find the right way to fix this issue with value `all`. can someone please point me in the right direction or explain what am I missing here.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Having the same issue.